# How do I find if my video driver is working

Tags: drivers

I use xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver software and I want to check if it is working.

I checked a box in the Driver Manager, but I am not sure it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System Settings... > System > Details` Under 'Graphics', you will see something like `GeForce GTX 760/PCIe/SSE2` I'm using the same drivers, and that's what shows up for me.

Another way to verify that they're in use is to open your terminal and type in `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`. Look for the line that says `Kernel driver in use` If it says `nvidia`, you have the driver installed. To make sure that you have hardware 3D acceleration, type in `glxinfo | grep OpenGL | grep renderer` If it says anything other than MESA, you're in luck.

To get CUDA up and running for 3D rendering and such, type in one final command: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe`. This enables CUDA for the full experience. Once that's all finished, restart your computer.